# For web scraping and xml parsing, which is best library to learn

Tags: beautifulsoup, scrapy, elementtree, minidom, celementtree

I am getting confused with multiple libraries for the same work. I want to learn to one library which will handle both xml and html parsing. Do elementtree is compatible for html parsing. I heard about lxml, xml.elementtree, beautifulsoup, minidom, scrapy. Can anybody help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Scrapy** is used for scraping web pages (extracting data from web pages) hence the name.

**Beautiful Soup** is library for parsing/pulling data from XML and HTML files.

**xml.elementtree** provides object representation of the XML file and it is a  XML processing module of Python XML package. It is neat to use for parsing and manipulating data in XML format.

**lxml** is as they claim compatible yet superior to elementtree of the Python XML module but essentially does the same however, I never used it for parsing of HTML files.

In my experience I used Scrapy for fetching data from various user panels that did not have any kind of API for pulling the data. However, parsing of HTML files I mostly did with Beautiful Soup as it is really neat and easy to use.
Regarding XML parsing I mostly used Python XML package however, I never had any complicated XML parsing to perform so Python XML package covered everything I need.

The right tool really depends on your requirements. If you need library to parse XML and HTML files both I would go with Beautiful Soup as it is really easy to use and you have vast documentation online.